# How to create a complex PL/SQL procedure with Python, cx_Oracle

Tags: python-3.x, plsql, procedure, cx-oracle

I have a multi-line PL/SQL procedure, which I have to create.

The SQL procedure is similar to the one below,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE HELLO AS
TYPE cur_cur is REF CURSOR;
v_cur_cur cur_cur;
age NUMBER;
day VARCHAR2(10);
date DATE;
BEGIN
   <Some Execute Immediate stmts>
   <Some insert stmts>
commit;
END;
```

Currently what I am doing is,

```
host= "localhost"
port= 1521
sid= "abcbcadacsw.com"
user= "groups"
password= "hello!bye1209"


dsn_tns = oracledb.makedsn(host, port, service_name=sid)
print(dsn_tns)

db_conn = oracledb.connect(user=user, password=password, dsn=dsn_tns)

curs= db_conn.cursor()

curs.execute("""

 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE HELLO AS
 TYPE cur_cur is REF CURSOR;
 v_cur_cur cur_cur;
 age NUMBER;
 day VARCHAR2(10);
 date DATE;
 BEGIN
  <Some Execute Immediate stmts>
  <Some insert stmts>
commit;
 END;


""")
```

The thing is the code runs without any issues, there are not runtime errors or anything ... but when i log into the DB to check for the created procedure, its not present. When i try to execute the procedure, it says 'identifier must be declared ... '.

I have tried converting it into a single line

```
curs.execute("""CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE HELLO AS TYPE cur_cur is REF CURSOR; v_cur_cur cur_cur; age NUMBER; day VARCHAR2(10); date DATE; BEGIN <Some Execute Immediate stmts> <Some insert stmts> commit; END;""")
```

This also does not work.
Please assist, ignore the correctness of the above shown procedure, i cannot put the original here, and i dont know much of SQL, i just need to  know how to successfully create it in Python.

Comment: So how are you calling the stored procedure? It would help to know that, too!

Comment: Does the problem only arise when the procedure is complex?

Answer (score 0):

The driver doesn't (yet) return Oracle DB's 'success with info' errors so if there is a problem with the PL/SQL code you won't find out about it unless you explicitly query the error view.

In SQL*Plus:

```
create or replace procedure fred as
begin
  f();
end;
/
```

would give:

```
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
```

and a subsequent  `show errors` will give

```
Errors for PROCEDURE FRED:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/3  PL/SQL: Statement ignored
3/3  PLS-00201: identifier 'F' must be declared
```

With cx_Oracle (and its new version [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a)) you don't get the initial indication there was a problem so you always should do the equivalent of the `show errors` command to check the error view.  Try something like:

```
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = """create or replace procedure fred as
                 begin
                   f();
                 end;"""
        cursor.execute(sql)

        sql = """select name, type, line, position, text
                 from user_errors
                 order by name, type, line, position"""
        for r in cursor.execute(sql):
            print(r)
```

which will show output like:

```
('FRED', 'PROCEDURE', 3, 20, 'PL/SQL: Statement ignored')
('FRED', 'PROCEDURE', 3, 20, "PLS-00201: identifier 'F' must be declared")
```

This is shown in the documentation [Creating Stored Procedures and Packages](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html#creating-stored-procedures-and-packages).